# How to design a table need to be queried on every field?

Tags: mysql, sql, rdbms

Now I met a application requirement to build a database that can be queried for every field. Say, the table is supposed to have 30 fields.

| f1 | f2 | f3 | ...  |f30|

The frontend may needs to query based on multiple or even all fields. For example, need to query all rows with f1 == x AND f2 < y AND f3 > z AND ... AND f30 = abc.

If I create index for each fields, insertion and update operation would be slow. If I just index some fields, query with un-indexed fields would be slow.

I suppose this is a common problem in a lot of application area. Is there any mature solution for this kind of case?

Comment: if the table will start empty, just collect statistics for the first few weeks, then create indexes for the most used columns - then update the statistics and indexes after a while...

Comment: If your table is normalized, you would only need to query by id and a few other fields, An example of your table structure would help us in helping you.

Answer (score 2):

You should set it up as a name/value pair table. One "field" for the field name and one "field" for the value. You would have a third field that would be the "record ID" linking all the record together. So in your example, each "entry" would have 30 records. Then you only need 1 index on the field name+field value, and you can add as many "fields" as you like without needing to alter the table structure.

Comment: Retrieving a whole row from a 30-column table will require 30 joins.  EAV is called an anti-pattern for a reason.

Comment: To retrieve an entire "row" from an EAV table you just query on the "record ID", no joins. Querying for 2 "records" returns 60 rows and the front-end code would need to separate the "records". But yes, EAV does have it's issues and NoSQL does a far better job of managing "EAV" data.

Comment: Report writers (among other things) expect rows. So you need to do the joins either in the back end, in mid-tier code, or application code. In practice, nobody does it in application code, because that would require the joining to be duplicated in every reportable application (that is, in multiple languages).  Most systems that are in production don't use a middle tier. That means you're stuck with re-creating rows in the database server. So, 30 joins.

Answer (score 1):

Indexes implement a space/time tradeoff. An index on every column

- consumes more disk space,
- makes some SELECT statements faster, and
- makes some INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements slower (because the dbms has to maintain the index as well as the row).

Very few user queries will select a random set of columns from your table. You'll probably find that two or three columns are in almost every query. Some kind of index on those columns will speed up all the queries that use them. A good query engine will use the indexes to isolate a subset of all the rows, then do a sequential scan on that subset for all the unindexed columns in the WHERE clause.

Often, that's fast enough for everybody.  (Test, don't assume.)

If it isn't fast enough for everybody, then you examine query execution plans and user query patterns, take some performance measurements, add another index, and ask yourself whether you can live with the results.  Each additional index will consume disk space, speed up some SELECT statements, and slow down some INSERT and DELETE statements. (It's not common for users to notice how INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements have slowed down; they usually don't slow down by very much.)

At some point, you might find that the SELECTers start complaining about the INSERTers, and vice versa. Unless you're willing to consider more invasive performance improvements

- faster hardware,
- server tuning,
- moving some tables or indexes to faster disks,
- perhaps even changing to a different dbms,

you now have a political problem, not a technical one.